# Unable to uninstall .NET Core SDK install with visual studio and SQL server remains

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, uninstallation

I was having so much trouble setting up my system for .NET Core development. A year back or so I had a visual studio installed on my machine, but it was removed way back. But some of its remains were still in the system. So when I tried to fresh install the latest version of VS community edition(2019) from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ installation went well but I was getting way too many errors and warning while starting VS2019 and even while creating the project, as it was unable to find .NET core SDKs, however, they were there in the system as was added in an environment variable as well.

I finally decided to remove all remains of current and old VS installed on my system. And reinstall everything from scratch. It was very difficult to do this as most of the files were not getting uninstalled and giving errors, so I used MSI Inventory tool https://sqlgeekspro.com/uninstall-sql/ and succeed in uninstalling almost everything except couple of version of .NET Core SDKs. And I have also tried .NET Core uninstall tool https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab/releases but it does not work for SDKs which installed with VS this is its limitation.

Below given are the thing that I needed to uninstall and unable to,
[image]

When I try to uninstall .NET Core SDK 3.1.201 from Add/Remove Programs so I am getting this error.
[image]

And when I try to uninstall any of the Visual C++, I get this error:
[image]
and the logs are following

```
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:20]i001: Burn v3.10.4.4718, Windows v10.0 (Build 17134: Service Pack 0), path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{65e650ff-30be-469d-b63a-418d71ea1765}\VC_redist.x86.exe
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:20]i009: Command Line: '"-burn.clean.room=C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{65e650ff-30be-469d-b63a-418d71ea1765}\VC_redist.x86.exe" -burn.filehandle.attached=612 -burn.filehandle.self=628 /uninstall'
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\MOIZ~1.BAI\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20200503184720.log'
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[2D98:1BC8][2020-05-03T18:47:20]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '14.25.28508.3'
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i000: Setting version variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKey' to value '10.0.17134.677'
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 1
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Present, cached: Complete
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Present, cached: Complete
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT = v5.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:21]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Uninstall
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\MOIZ~1.BAI\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20200503184720_000_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86_rollback.log'
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\MOIZ~1.BAI\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20200503184720_000_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86.log'
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\MOIZ~1.BAI\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20200503184720_001_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86_rollback.log'
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\MOIZ~1.BAI\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20200503184720_001_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86.log'
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Unregister
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Unregister
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i300: Apply begin
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:22]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:28]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:28]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[16C0:0E80][2020-05-03T18:47:28]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[16C0:0E80][2020-05-03T18:47:28]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[16C0:0E80][2020-05-03T18:47:28]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[16C0:0E80][2020-05-03T18:47:30]i361: Created a system restore point.
[16C0:0E80][2020-05-03T18:47:30]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{65e650ff-30be-469d-b63a-418d71ea1765}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[16C0:0E80][2020-05-03T18:47:30]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, action: Uninstall, path: (null), arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[16C0:0E80][2020-05-03T18:47:30]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to uninstall MSI package.
[16C0:0E80][2020-05-03T18:47:30]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:30]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:30]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:30]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[16C0:0E80][2020-05-03T18:47:30]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{65e650ff-30be-469d-b63a-418d71ea1765}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[16C0:0E80][2020-05-03T18:47:30]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{65e650ff-30be-469d-b63a-418d71ea1765}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[2D98:0344][2020-05-03T18:47:30]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

And when I try to uninstall the SQL server error appears as per given below,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall sdk versions that were installed via the Visual Studio installer you need to modify your installation using the installer again.

So to bypass this error:

[image]

You must uncheck the SDK option for your Visual Studio in the installer and modify your installation:
[image]